# Additional bluetooth adapters not showing up

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I have two [BleuIO](https://www.bleuio.com/) bluetooth adapters plugged into my laptop, which has an internal bluetooth adapter as well. The BleuIOs do not show up as controller using hcitool:

```
~$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    B4:8C:9D:BD:DA:B6
```

and also not using bluetoothctl:

```
~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller B4:8C:9D:BD:DA:B6 Pairable: yes
[bluetooth]# list
Controller B4:8C:9D:BD:DA:B6 <laptop-name> [default]
```

How can I make these controllers visible?

I want to use them with [the Movella SDK](https://www.movella.com/support/software-documentation) which can also find only `hci0`. I am on Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Comment: Install hardinfo or equivalent  (sudo apt install hardinfo). See if your bluetooth hardware is working